# Java Regexp clarification

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like :

```
<RandomText>
executeRule(x, y, z)
<MoreRandomText>
```

What I would like to accomplish is the following: if this `executeRule` string exists in the bigger text block, I would like to get its 2'nd parameter.

How could I do this ?

Comment: Will it always have three parameters?

Comment: It will always have 3 parameters; the parameters are strings as well....x,y,z can vary from one function call to the other.

Comment: "x, y, **z**" or "x, y, **x**" ? is a difference!

Comment: x,y,z sorry. Found a solution. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean the bigger text block?

If you want to extract the second param from that expression, it would be something like

```
executeRule\(\w+,\s*(\w+),\s*\w+\)
```

The second param is held on capture group $1.

Keep in mind that to use this expression in Java, you need to escape the '\'. Also, I'm just assuming \w is good enough to match your params, that would depend on your particular rules.

If you need some help with actually using regexes in Java, there are many resources you can turn to, I found this tutorial to be fairly simple and it explains the basic usages:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("executeRule\\(\\w+, (\\w+), \\w+\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(YOUR_TEXT_FROM_FILE);
while (m.find()) {
  String secondArgument = m.group(1);
  ...process secondArgument...
}
```

Once this code executes `secondArgument` will contain the value of `y`. The above regular expression assumes that you expect the arguments to be composed of word characters (i.e. small and capital letters, digits and underscore).

Double backslashes are needed by Java string literal syntax, regexp engine will see single backslashes.

If you'd like to allow for whitespace in the string as it is allowed in most programming languages, you may use the following regexp:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("executeRule\\(\\s*\\w+\\s*,\\s*(\\w+)\\s*,\\s*\\w+\\s*\\)");
```